# 2nd row is not getting inserted with BitVector in Apache Arrow Flight Sql in Java

Tags: apache-arrow, bitvector, apache-arrow-flight

**main.java**

```
Schema schema = new Schema(mtasks.asFlightFieldList(), metadata);

try (VectorSchemaRoot vectorSchemaRoot = VectorSchemaRoot.create(schema, rootAllocator)) {
  VarCharVector idVector = (VarCharVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("ID");
  idVector.allocateNew(1);
  idVector.set(0, mtasks.getId().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 
  BitVector bitVector = (BitVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("MOPT1");
  bitVector.allocateNew(1);
  bitVector.setSafe(0,mtasks.getMopT1() ? 1 : 0);
  bitVector.setValueCount(1);
 
  vectorSchemaRoot.setRowCount(1);
 
 var listener = 
      flightClient.startPut(FlightDescriptor.path("//" + dbSchemaName + "/" + tableName),
      vectorSchemaRoot, new AsyncPutListener());
 
   listener.putNext();
   listener.completed();
   listener.getResult();
 }
 
 
 **POJO class**
 
private final Map<String, ?> properties;
 
public mtasks(Map<String, ?> properties) {
  this.properties = properties;
}
 
public mtasks(String ID, Boolean bitVector) {
   Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
   properties.put("BITVECTOR",bitvector);
   properties.put("ID", ID);
   this.properties = properties;
 }

public List<Field> asFlightFieldList() {
   return Arrays.asList(
   new Field("bitvector", new FieldType(false, new ArrowType.Bool(), null), null),
   new Field("ID", new FieldType(false, new ArrowType.Utf8(), null), null));
 }
```

I am creating `vectorschemaroot` and trying to get `fieldvector` of type boolean utilizing Apache arrow flight Sql and insert the data into database.

1st row is getting inserted but 2nd and so on is not inserting. Also, No error/exception is coming.

I tried to debug till `listener.getResult()` and transaction is getting succeeded.